# Displaying files in IE using an asynchronous pluggable protocol

Tags: internet-explorer, protocols, pluggableprotocol

I have created an asynchronous pluggable protocol for Internet Explorer :

ex://D:/sample.html        (assume "ex" to be the protocol created by me)

opens the file D:/sample.html file in the IE itself

Following are the issues:

1. Its able to render html and jpeg(havn't checked other image file formats) files. But it displays the error "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" for other file formats such as .doc, .pdf, .swf, etc. According to the logs where I am recording stages of processing, the entire processing is going on similarly for these file formats as in the case of html etc.
2. After we open a file in IE, the file is opened in the IE using the default application being registered for the file format in the system. For example: a pdf file is opened in adobe reader in systems where adobe reader is the default application registered for pdf file format. So is there any way we can control UI controls(such as save, print,etc) of that default application programatically while the document is being displayed.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my test protocol: (tp://) on [codeplex](http://tpapp.codeplex.com/). It does handle various types by reporting MIME type.

Comment: The problem is when I fetch data from a file in my protocol handler, and IE reads it, IE is able to render it properly. But when I manipulate data and IE reads the manipulated data, IE is not able to render it properly. The manipulated data is kept in binary byte array format. It seems to be an encoding issue to me, but I am not sure what to do. (Files include ppt, pdf, docx, etc files)

Comment: Try removing flag USE_IE_ENCODING from BindInfo. That effectively instructs IE to not compress data though